# Fast Prime Sieve (Python Implementation)

Tags: python, performance, beginner, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

A modified version of the prime sieve. I actually doubt it could be implemented any faster, but I might be wrong:

```py
from math import sqrt

def sieve(n):
    """
        *   A fast implementation of the prime sieve algorithm. Finds all prime numbers up to a given upper bound.

        *   Params:
            *   n: The upper bound.
        *   Return:
            *   A list of all prime numbers in [0, n].
        *   Implementation:
            *   Implements the sieve of Erasthotenes with a few optimisations for speed.
            *   We only delete multiples of numbers up to `int(sqrt(n))`. This suffices to find all prime numbers.
            *   We manipulate a list of boolean values, indexed by the number itself with the values denoting its primality. This is much faster than deleting elements in the list.
    """
    if n < 2:   return []
    prime = [True]*(n + 1)      #Initialise the list.
    rt = int(sqrt(n))+1
    for x in range(2, rt):      #We only need to seive multiples of numbers <= to `n`.
        if prime[x]:
            for c in range(x*x, n + 1, x):      prime[c] = False
    return [idx for idx, p in enumerate(prime) if p][2:]
```

Comment: Please always include a language tag with your question. With Python it's also best to include one of [tag:python-3.x] or [tag:python-2.x] if your question is targeting that environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is tagged [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner), you should know that speed isn't everything. First of all you should care about making your code readable as ultimately that is more important.

- You should always put new statements on new lines. At first I ignored your first guard statement, due to this. I only caught on that you'd done this when I saw the second from last line was huge.
- Your comments aren't great. Yes `[True]*(n + 1)` initializes a list, we can read the code to understand that.
- Your variable names don't really help reading the code.

```
def sieve(limit):
    if limit < 2:
        return []

    limit += 1  # Preincrement `limit` so `sieve` is inclusive, unlike `range`.
    primes = [True]*limit
    for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
        if primes[base]:
            for composite in range(base*2, limit, base):
                primes[composite] = False
    return [num for num, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime][2:]
```

I'd like to point out that your memory usage can be improved. How many \$O(n)\$ lists do you have?

1. `primes` to perform the sieve.
2. Your list comprehension, that gets all the indexes.
3. Your duplication of the list comprehension to remove *two* values.

You can remove the second by returning an iterator. As for the third, you can instead perform an [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), or setting 0 and 1 to false. Yes this is now 10% slower.

However if you change the second for loop to run in C land rather than Python land you net a 40% speed-up from the original.

```
from math import ceil


def sieve(limit):
    if limit < 2:
        return []

    limit += 1  # Preincrement `limit` so sieve is inclusive, unlike `range`.
    primes = [True]*limit
    for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
        if primes[base]:
            primes[base*2:limit:base] = [False]*(ceil(limit / base) - 2)

    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    return (num for num, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime)
```

From this changing the last line to use `itertools.compress` rather than an iterator comprehension reduces time an additional 40% (nearly 70% from the original).

```
from math import ceil
from itertools import compress


def sieve(limit):
    if limit < 2:
        return []

    limit += 1  # Preincrement `limit` so sieve is inclusive, unlike `range`.
    primes = [True]*limit
    for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
        if primes[base]:
            primes[base*2:limit:base] = [False]*(ceil(limit / base) - 2)

    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    return compress(range(limit), primes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am not so sure why you removed `sqrt()` though? Wouldn't it be faster than `n**0.5`? Also, I don't understand what this line of code does: `primes[base*2:limit:base] = [False]*(ceil(limit / base) - 2)`. Could you please explain?

Comment: @TobiAlafin Preference and speed. `timeit("sqrt(10000)", "from math import sqrt", number=100000000)` -> 9.42233170700274, `timeit("10000 ** 0.5", number=100000000)` -> 0.8613513769996644. It's called [vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47755442), in short Python slow, C fast, do everything in C.

Comment: Nice idea with the slice assignment. I thought doing `primes[base*base:limit:base] = [False]*((((limit - base*base) - 1) // base) + 1)` would be even faster, since the slice is a bit smaller, but it seems to be exactly the same speed...

Comment: @Graipher Oh, I guess late last night I didn't notice the difference between `n*n` and `n*2`, oops. That's interesting, wouldn't have thought changing a couple hundred/thousand values at a time would run that quickly. Did you test with larger limits? Mine are at 10000.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: Yes, I tested up to 1E7...

Comment: @Graipher Oh wow :O

Comment: @Peilonrayz: Here's the plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb2Pe.png

Comment: @Graipher Wow, that really is negligible. Do you have a GitHub repro for that [timing graph stuff](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/165245)?

Comment: @Peilonrayz: No I don't, but that sounds like a good idea. I'll ping you when I have it set up, might take a bit, still gotta work in between SE...

Comment: @Graipher No rush :) Look forward to it