# Fast prime generator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, primes

I wanted to test my performance optimizing skills, and so wanted to find how fast I could get the first \$n\$ prime numbers. I limited myself to only the standard library, as I'm sure `numpy` or another library written in C has a prime generator *way* faster than Python ever will be - and offloading to a library doesn't really improve my ability to improve performance.

I've implemented both the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the Sieve of Sundaram. The SoE was based off my answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213422), and the SoS was based off [Wikipedias definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram#Algorithm). These are available at the end of the answer.

I improved performance by:

- SoE: Vectorizing the creation of primes.

  ```
  primes[base*2:limit:base] = [False]*(ceil(limit / base) - 2)
  ```
- SoE: Change the start of the slice from \$2b\$ to \$b^2\$. <sup>[[1]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/213418#comment412884_213422)</sup>

  ```
  primes[base*base:limit:base] = [False]*((((limit - base*base) - 1) // base) + 1)
  ```
- SoE: Simplify the calculations - addition seems to be faster than multiplication.

  ```
  primes[base * base::base] = [False] * ((limit - 1) // base - base + 1)
  ```
- SoE: Use `itertools.compress`, rather than a comprehension.
- SoS: Vectorize the inner loop.

  ```
  start = 1 + 3*j
  step = 1 + 3*j
  primes[start::step] = [False] * ceil((n - start) / step)
  ```
- SoS: Vectorize the creation of values that only have one value in the sequence.

  When \$\frac{n - \text{start}}{\text{stop}} = \frac{n - (1 + 3j)}{1 + 2j} \le 1\$ is equivalent to \$n \le 2 + 5j\$ we know we can stop at \$j = \frac{n - 2}{5}\$.

  ```
  multi_stop = (n - 2) // 5
  for j in range(1, multi_stop):
      start = 1 + 3*j
      step = 1 + 2*j
      primes[start::step] = [False] * ceil((n - start) / step)

  if multi_stop >= 1:
      single_start = multi_stop * 3 + 1
      primes[single_start::3] = [False] * ceil((n - single_start) / 3)
  ```
- SoS: It doesn't seem like you need the `if` created above, and so you can just save wasted cycles.

I tried defining `false = [False]*limit` and slice it, but found it to be slower than creating new lists in the loop.

This got the following prime sieves:

```
from math import ceil
from itertools import compress


def sieve_eratosthenes(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    primes = [True] * limit
    for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
        if primes[base]:
            primes[base * base::base] = [False] * ((limit - 1) // base - base + 1)

    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    return list(compress(range(limit), primes))


def sieve_sundaram(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    n = (limit - 1) // 2
    primes = [True] * n
    for j in range(1, (n - 2) // 5):
        start = 1 + 3*j
        step = 1 + 2*j
        primes[start::step] = [False] * ceil((n - start) / step)

    return [2] + [2*i + 1 for i, p in enumerate(primes) if p][1:]
```

Both are faster than the both the original functions.

[image]
[image]

Code to generate graphs:

```
from math import ceil
from itertools import compress

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from graphtimer import Plotter, MultiTimer


def sieve_eratosthenes_orig(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    primes = [True] * limit
    for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
        if primes[base]:
            for composite in range(base * 2, limit, base):
                primes[composite] = False
    return [num for num, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime][2:]


def sieve_eratosthenes(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    primes = [True] * limit
    for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
        if primes[base]:
            primes[base * base::base] = [False] * ((limit - 1) // base - base + 1)

    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    return list(compress(range(limit), primes))


def sieve_sundaram_orig(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    n = (limit - 1) // 2
    primes = [True] * n
    for j in range(1, n):
        for i in range(1, j + 1):
            value = i + j + 2*i*j
            if value < n:
                primes[value] = False

    return [2] + [2*i + 1 for i, p in enumerate(primes) if p][1:]


def sieve_sundaram(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    n = (limit - 1) // 2
    primes = [True] * n
    for j in range(1, (n - 2) // 5):
        start = 1 + 3*j
        step = 1 + 2*j
        primes[start::step] = [False] * ceil((n - start) / step)

    return [2] + [2*i + 1 for i, p in enumerate(primes) if p][1:]


def sieve_test(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    n = (limit - 1) // 2
    primes = [True] * n
    multi_stop = (n - 2) // 5
    for j in range(1, multi_stop):
        start = 1 + 3*j
        step = 1 + 2*j
        primes[start::step] = [False] * ceil((n - start) / step)

    return [2] + [2*i + 1 for i, p in enumerate(primes) if p][1:]


def test():
    for exp in range(6):
        limit = 10 ** exp
        assert sieve_test(limit) == sieve_eratosthenes(limit)


def main():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots()
    axs.set_yscale('log')
    axs.set_xscale('log')
    (
        Plotter(MultiTimer([
            sieve_eratosthenes_orig,
            sieve_eratosthenes,
            sieve_sundaram,
            sieve_sundaram_orig,
            # sieve_test,
        ]))
            .repeat(5, 5, np.logspace(0.35, 2), args_conv=int)
            .min()
            .plot(axs, x_label='limit')
    )
    fig.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    main()
```

To use the above code snippet you need to install numpy, matplotlib and graphtimer. All should be available via pypi.

Can they be made faster, or is a different sieve faster?

Comment: Did you try the [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin)? Something tells me it's faster than the Sieve of Erathosthenes.

Comment: @Justin No, I didn't. I'm not too sure about it being faster than SoE in _Python_. But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Here, I might have just found something - https://programmingpraxis.com/2010/02/19/sieve-of-atkin-improved/. Does this help?

Comment: @Justin Since it was written for Python 2 it may be unfair for it to be performance tested in Python 3. However with `xrange = range` and ensuring no IndexErrors I get the following [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ckb.png). Which makes it faster than SoS at 1000 and always slower than SoE.

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> def sieve_eratosthenes(limit):
>     if limit <= 1:
>         return []
>
>     primes = [True] * limit
>     for base in range(2, int(limit**0.5 + 1)):
>         if primes[base]:
>             primes[base * base::base] = [False] * ((limit - 1) // base - base + 1)
>
>     primes[0] = primes[1] = False
>     return list(compress(range(limit), primes))
> ```

No attempt at all to use a wheel? I get roughly a 25% speedup just by special-casing the prime 2 with:

```
def sieve_eratosthenes_wheel(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    primes = [True] * limit
    if limit > 4:
        primes[4::2] = [False] * ((limit - 1) // 2 - 2 + 1)

    for base in range(3, int(limit**0.5 + 1), 2):
        if primes[base]:
            # We require off + (len-1)*step < limit <= off + len*step
            # So len = ceil((limit - off) / step)
            primes[base*base::2*base] = [False] * ((limit - base*base + 2*base - 1) // (2*base))

    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    return list(compress(range(limit), primes))
```

Using primes 2 and 3 it's possible to do two range updates with step sizes of `6*base`, but it gets more complicated to calculate the initial offsets, which depend on `base % 6`:

```
def sieve_eratosthenes_wheel3(limit):
    if limit <= 1:
        return []

    primes = [True] * limit
    def mark_composite(off, step):
        # We require off + (len-1)*step < limit <= off + len*step
        # So len = ceil((limit - off) / step)
        primes[off::step] = [False] * ((limit - off + step - 1) // step)

    mark_composite(4, 2)
    mark_composite(9, 6)
    base = 5
    max_base = int(limit**0.5)
    while base <= max_base:
        # base == 5 (mod 6)
        if primes[base]:
            mark_composite(base*base, 6*base)
            mark_composite(base*(base+2), 6*base)
        base += 2
        # base == 1 (mod 6)
        if primes[base]:
            mark_composite(base*base, 6*base)
            mark_composite(base*(base+4), 6*base)
        base += 4

    primes[0] = primes[1] = False
    return list(compress(range(limit), primes))
```

For `limit` 50 million, taking `sieve_eratosthenes` as the baseline of 100 time units, I measure `sieve_eratosthenes_wheel` at about 73 time units and `sieve_eratosthenes_wheel3` at about 63 time units.

Comment: Could you explain what "a wheel" is? I know car wheels, but this meaning is definitely new to me :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization