# Prime sieve in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I was trying to write Sieve for the first time and I came up with this code:

```
def sieve(num):
    numbers = set(range(3, num, 2))
    for i in range(3, int(num**(1/2)) + 1 , 2):
        num_set = set(i*c for c in range(3, num//2, 2))
        numbers = numbers - num_set
    return list(sorted((2, *numbers)))
```

The problem is that for `num > 10**6` the time to create prime numbers increases.

**Also, when I tried `num = 10**8` my computer stopped working, started to make awkward noises and I had to restart it.**

I think the problem is that I am dealing with sets. For large numbers (for instance, in `num = 10**8` case) the set cannot be produced since my computer cannot process that much information, hence it stops.

Is there a way to solve this memory or time problem using my code or should use a different algorithm?

Comment: Say each number in a set in Python takes up 80 bytes - 10 64bit registers - then your program is going to need 10GB of memory. What, you don't have 10GB of memory, well then your PC's just offed itself.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 I am sorry, I did not know that. I'll be more careful from now on.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? The `//` implies 3 to me, but I'd like that confirmed.

Comment: @NicHartley The `*numbers` uses the unpacking operator, which is only in Python3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using a `set()` is your bottleneck, memory-wise.

```
>>> numbers = set(range(3, 10**8, 2))
>>> sys.getsizeof(numbers)
2147483872
>>> sys.getsizeof(numbers) + sum(map(sys.getsizeof, numbers))
3547483844
```

A `set` of odd numbers up to 100 million is consuming <strike>2GB</strike> 3.5GB (thank-you @ShadowRanger) of memory.  When you do an operation like `numbers = numbers - num_set`, you'll need to have 3 sets in memory at once.  One for the original set, one for the set of numbers you are removing, and one for the resulting set.  This will be greater than <strike>4GB</strike> 7GB of memory, since some of the numbers you are removing aren't in the original set.

You don't need to realize the entire set of numbers you are removing in memory.  You could simply remove the numbers from the set one at a time:

```
for c in range(3, num // 2, 2):
    numbers.remove(i * c)
```

This is modifying the set in place, so the memory requirement will not exceed the initial 2GB of memory for the set.

---

Why are you looping `c` over `range(3, num // 2, 2)`?  This is doing way too much work.  The maximum value `c` should obtain should satisfy `i*c < num`, since no product `i*c` larger than `num` will be in the original set.

You should instead loop over `range(3, num // i + 1, 2)`.  This will decrease the size of the set of numbers you are removing as the prime numbers you find increase.

---

Why start removing primes at `3*i`?  When `i` is 97, you've already removed multiples of 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, ... up to 89. The first multiple you need to remove is `97*97`.  You would then continue with `99*97`, `101*97`, and so on, up to `num`.  So the `range` should begin with `i`, not `3`.

```
for c in range(i, num // i + 1, 2):
    numbers.remove(i * c)
```

Actually, this is still too complicated.  Let's get rid of the multiplication.  This also greatly simplifies the upper limit of the range.

```
for multiple in range(i*i, num, 2*i):
    numbers.remove(multiple)
```

Or equivalently, passing a generator to `difference_update` to remove items in bulk, but without realizing the set of numbers to be removed in memory simultaneously.

```
numbers.difference_update(multiple for multiple in range(i*i, num, 2*i))
```

---

Even with all of the above changes, you still require 2GB of memory to compute the primes up to 100 million.  And since a `set` is unordered, you still have to `sort` the surviving numbers afterwards to get your ordered list of primes.

A better way is to maintain an array of flags, one per candidate number.  With 100 million candidate numbers, if each flag used only a single byte, you'd only require 100 MB of memory, a savings of a factor of 20.  And since the array of flags is ordered, no sorting of the array would be required.

The [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray) is one such structure.  It is an array of bytes.  You can store your candidates in the array as a `1`, and any non-primes (multiples of other primes) as `0`.

```
def sieve(num):
    flags = bytearray(num)      # Initially, all bytes are zero

    flags[2] = 1                # Two is prime
    for i in range(3, num, 2):
        flags[i] = 1            # Odd numbers are prime candidates

    # Find primes and eliminate multiples of those primes
    for i in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if flags[i]:
            for multiple in range(i * i, num, 2 * i):
                flags[multiple] = 0

    return [ i for i, flag in enumerate(flags) if flag ]
```

---

Conserving a little bit more memory, you can store your list of primes in an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/array.html)

```
import array

def sieve(num):
    flags = bytearray(num)      # Initially, all bytes are zero

    flags[2] = 1                # Two is prime
    for i in range(3, num, 2):
        flags[i] = 1            # Odd numbers are prime candidates

    # Find primes and eliminate multiples of those primes
    for i in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if flags[i]:
            for multiple in range(i * i, num, 2 * i):
                flags[multiple] = 0

    return array.array('I', (i for i, flag in enumerate(flags) if flag))
```

For primes up to \$10^8\$, the `array.array('I', ...)` stores the 5.7 million primes in a mere 23MB of memory.  The list version takes a whopping 212MB.

**Note**: If you are using a 32-bit version of Python, you may need the type-code `'L'` instead of `'I'` to get storage for 4-byte integers in the array.

---

For the truly memory conscious, install the `bitarray` module.

```
pip3 install bitarray
```

In addition to using only a single bit per flag, for 1/8th the memory usage in the sieve, it allows some truly fantastic slice assignments from a single boolean scalar, which makes clearing all multiples of a prime number into a simple single statement.

```
import array
from bitarray import bitarray

def sieve(num):

    flags = bitarray(num)
    flags.setall(False)
    flags[2] = True                      # Two is prime
    flags[3::2] = True                   # Odd numbers are prime candidates

    for i in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if flags[i]:
            flags[i*i:num:2*i] = False   # Eliminate multiples of this prime

    primes = array.array('I', (i for i, flag in enumerate(flags) if flag))

    return primes
```

Timings:

```
10^3:  0.000
10^4:  0.000
10^5:  0.004
10^6:  0.051
10^7:  0.428
10^8:  4.506
```

**Note**: Updated timing info.  I just noticed I had `for i in range(3, num + 1, 2)` in the last implementation instead of `for i in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2)`, resulting in a lot of wasted time doing nothing.

**Python 3.8 Update**: Using [`math.isqrt(num)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=isqrt#math.isqrt) is better than `int(num ** 0.5)`:

```
    for i in range(3, math.isqrt(num) + 1, 2):
```

Comment: A note: `sys.getsizeof(numbers)` is only telling you the size of the `set` structure itself, not all the `int`s stored in it. The very smallest `int`s are singletons, (CPython implementation detail), but you'd have to pay the memory cost of all the rest, so the memory used is `sys.getsizeof(numbers) + sum(map(sys.getsizeof, numbers))`, which on a 64 bit build of Python adds just shy of another 1.4 GB of memory onto the cost, starting at 28 bytes per `int` for magnitudes of 30 bits and below, adding four more bytes for every additional 30 bits of magnitude or part thereof.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Excellent point.  I did that for the list to get the 212MB, but neglected to do so for the `numbers` set.

Comment: Great answer. Exactly what I needed. I actually changed my code a bit after the Jackson's answer (that range parts). However it was against the rules so I couldn't change my code in the post.

Comment: What does `flags[i*i:num:2*i]` do exactly? You say it removes multiples of a prime, but I'm not exactly sure how this notation works.

Comment: @Nzall `flags[start:stop:step]` references a “slice” of the `flags` bit array, beginning with the `start` element, then the `start+step` element, then the `start+2*step` element, all the way up to (but not including) the `stop` element.  Since we start at a multiple of the current prime, and go up by a multiple of the prime, these elements all have indices which are multiples of the prime.  The `= False` assigns all of those elements in the bit array to false, which doesn’t remove those elements, but flags them as not prime candidates, so “removes” them from consideration.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I see. I now also realize that you  start at the square of the prime because every multiple of the prime before that has already been falsified by earlier prime falsifications.

Comment: For `flags = bytearray(num)` you might want to look at `type(flags[0])` and `sys.getsizeof(flags[0)`.

Comment: @DavidCullen You might want to try `flags[0] = 300`.  Even though `flags[0]` returns an integer (`type(flags[0])` returns `<class 'int'>`), it can only hold a value between 0 and 255, because the storage for it is a single byte.  Compare `sys.getsizeof(bytearray(1))` and `sys.getsizeof(bytearray(1001))`.  57 bytes of overhead, but then 1 byte of memory per element in the array.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a way to solve this memory or time problem using my code or should use a different algorithm?

The *algorithm* is fine for the kind of scale you're talking about. It's the *implementation* of the algorithm which needs optimisation.

To tackle the memory issue, look at `set`. Given that the elements of the set are integers from a fixed range and moderately dense in that range (about 1 in 18 numbers up to \$10^8\$ are prime) the ideal would be a data structure which uses 1 bit per number. (I'm not sure whether one is available in Python. In the worst case, since it has big integers you can use bit manipulations on numbers). But failing that, a simple array of Boolean values probably has less overhead than a set.

---

> ```
> return list(sorted((2, *numbers)))
> ```

This is actually quite heavy-weight. It's probably not the bottleneck, but it might be worth asking yourself whether the caller needs a list. Perhaps you can use `yield` inside the main loop and skip the post-processing altogether. Perhaps the memory pressure isn't so bad as to prevent you from accumulating the list in order. And if the memory pressure is a problem, perhaps you can break the set into *pages*, something like (**warning:** code not tested, and this doesn't include the other ideas I've mentioned):

```
primes = [2]
page_size = 1000000
for page_start in range(3, num, page_size):
    page_end = min(num, page_start + page_size)
    page = set(range(page_start, page_end, 2))
    for p in primes:
        remove multiples of p from page
    for p in range(page_start, page_end, 2):
        if p in page:
            primes.append(p)
            remove multiples of p from page
```

---

Note: I've thrown out several ideas. I understand that you're doing this as a learning exercise, and trying out various different directions should be useful for that purpose even if you conclude that there isn't enough benefit to compensate for the added complexity.

Comment: In general I dont need to turn set into list however when I need indexing, for instance, I will need to turn it to list. I dont know much anything about the bit manupilation...

Comment: [My versions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221659) which uses a Boolean list can't work with \$n=10^8\$ with 32GB of memory. Chunking up the values is a good idea tho, probably could get it so it uses a list with vectorization pretty easily.

Answer (score 9):

I think your performance problems at 10**6 elements start here:

```
for i in range(3, int(num**(1/2)) + 1 , 2):
```

This generates a list of numbers that you then build a set of multiples from and remove those multiples from the numbers set.  But this generates a set [3,5,7,9,11,13,15,...] so when you've removed all the multiples of 3 you still try and remove multiples of [9,15,21,...] all of which went when you removed the multiples of three.

In a classic implementation of sieve you would find the next smallest prime and remove that, then find the next smallest prime and remove that until you get to the square root of num.

For example with num = 25 :

- [], [3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25] -- remove multiples of 3
- [3], [5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25] - 5 is next lowest so remove its   multiples
- [3,5], [7,11,13,17,19,23] - we've reached the square root
  of num, only primes left

So after each removal you want to find the new minimal element left in numbers but the problem with the set is that it's unordered so operation like min() is an O(N) operation, the entire set has to be scanned.  You may be able to get round this by looking for an OrderedSet implementation, in which case each time you find a prime you remove it's multiples, remove the prime itself to a separate set say, and the next prime to remove is the minimal value in the numbers set.

As Peilonrayz points out in a comment, when you start to get toward 10*8 elements you need to think about how much memory these sets are going to need.  You might well need a data structure that uses a lot less memory.

Comment: thanks my code now runs 8x faster. It can calculate up to `10**6` in 3.5 sec

Comment: Depending on the Python version, this might or might not generate a `list` (the Python type). I'm pretty sure this is Python 3, which means that, no, memory isn't a concern with the `range` statement, as it'll always be stored as just 3 ints in a special object, and the iterator will probably just store 1 int (the index). It's still a _performance_ concern to hit all those unnecessary numbers, of course, just not a _memory_ one. What might be causing memory issues is the `set(...)` bit, which _does_ store that whole thing.

Comment: @ I agree with you