# Exceeded time limit to solve super pow

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I tried to solve the [Super Pow - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/super-pow/)

> 372. Super Pow
>
> Medium
>
> Your task is to calculate *a*<sup>*b*</sup> mod 1337 where *a* is a positive integer and *b* is an extremely large positive integer given in the form of an array.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: a = 2, b = [3]
> Output: 8
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: a = 2, b = [1,0]
> Output: 1024
> ```

My solution

```py
import unittest
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s %(message)s")

class Solution(object):
    def superPow(self, a, b):
        """
        :type a: int
        :type b: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        digit = int("".join(map(str, b)))
        product = a ** digit 
        res = product % 1337
        return res

class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution()

    def test_1(self):
        a = 2
        b = [1, 0]
        answer = 1024
        check = self.solution.superPow(a, b)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)

unittest.main()
```

The solution exceeded the time limit.

How could I improve my solution?

Comment: *an extremely large positive integer given in the form of an array*" is far too vague for a specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's built-in [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) already has this functionality.

```
class Solution(object):
    def superPow(self, a, b):
        """
        :type a: int
        :type b: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        digit = int("".join(map(str, b)))
        return pow(a, digit, 1337)
```

The bottleneck then might be parsing the list of digits into the integer. To remedy that, you can try to use the fact that

\$
\begin{align}
a^{123} ~\text{mod}~ 1337 &= (a^{100}\cdot a^{20}\cdot a^3)~\text{mod}~ 1337& \\
              &= (a^{100}~\text{mod}~ 1337 \cdot a^{20}~\text{mod}~ 1337\cdot a^3  ~\text{mod}~ 1337) ~\text{mod}~ 1337& \\
\end{align}\$

```
class Solution(object):
    def superPow(self, a, b):
        """
        :type a: int
        :type b: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        ret = 1
        for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(b)):
            ret = (ret * pow(a, digit * 10**i, 1337)) % 1337
        return ret
```

---

And here are some timings for inputs of increasing length (from 1 to 10 digits, because your function would take way too long otherwise), with `a = 2` and where `super_pow_op` is your function, `super_pow_built_in` is my first function and `super_pow_expanded` is my second function.

[image]

And here for 3 to 1000 digits, but only with my two functions:

[image]

Comment: amazing, do you mind if I ask what' the tool you use to analyze the performance?

Comment: @Alice: I used the code in [my question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165245/plot-timings-for-a-range-of-inputs), plus the answer given there.